# dynamic image for autocomplete / components

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

I am trying to make a crypto react native app, I am trying to have icons to match with an autocomplete. So it would work very similar to the coinmarketcap search, where you can type a coin symbol and you will see the corresponding coin with its icon.

I think there could be a few ways to do this and I think this would be a good place for discussion on what is the best way.

For starters, I created a script that would take all the icons in a directory (SVG or PNG), and create a json that would have the symbol as the value and the key will be a reference to the icon.

With this method there are a few problems I have encountered. The solutions have been covered in this post.

[React Native - Dynamic Image Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41432626/react-native-dynamic-image-source).

However, it has been hard for me to find a good solution to either 
A. Encode all the image in a directory into a base64encoded string and put it into a json

B. Create an array on the React Native end which will have the require('path-to-image')

Relevant code examples are in the post so i dont want to repeat it, but I guess I would just like to know which one is the best practice. I think that doing it as a array of modules would be best. But I am not sure have to dynamically create something like that.

example of the dictionary I created is something like this:
Given a JSON object like this how would you extend it so it would become

```
const image = {
key1: 'path/to/key/one.png'
key2: 'path/to/key/two.png'
 }
```

To

```
{
key1: require('path/to/key/one.png'),
key2: require('path/to/key/two.png')
}
```

you would it to fit into a react native component like so

```
            <Image
                source={ (images[symbol])}
            />
```

Comment: Not sure if I totally understand -- is it that you don't know which / how many icons are contained in your assets folder?

Comment: I was using fs to map the files in a directory to a json, and importing it. The idea is to be able to get a reference to the asset through a lookup

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options, and I think you nailed the best one in your case (tested in React Native 0.50.3):

```
import {Image} from 'react-native'

export default (props) => <Image source={icons[props.currency]} />

const icons = {
    bitcoin: require('../path/to/bitcoin.png'),
    ethereum: require('../path/to/ethereum.png'),
    ...
}
```

Lol that's basically exactly what you already wrote in your question. I've also gotten away with storing a bunch of `require(...)` statements in an array and pulled by index, e.g:

```
import {Image} from 'react-native'

export default (props) => <Image source={icons[props.index]} />

const icons = [
    bitcoin: require('../path/to/bitcoin.png'),
    ethereum: require('../path/to/ethereum.png'),
    ...
]
```

This approach is really only useful if you don't know the key to identify your target reference by (e.g if you wanted to cycle through a bunch of images randomly). For the described use case I'd go with key lookup.

Comment: I guess my question is, how would one go about construacting that object dynamically. For example, from a json file where the key/value are the paths? when i try to instantiate such object, it seems to be executing the require statements and returning an error.

Comment: Ahh I see.. the best available option to my knowledge would be to keep your two files as such:
`/* icons.js */ export default = {bitcoin: require('path/to/bitcoin.png'), ethereum: require('path/to/ethereum.png'),...}`

`/* RenderedComponent.js */ import icons from './icons'; export default (props) => <Image source={icons[props.type]} />`

Unfortunately it seems the es5 `require` needs a string literal since it executes during the bundling phase(?)